# Bypassing the only_full_group_by restriction

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, sql-mode

I have this simple table:

```
mysql> select deviceId, eventName, loggedAt from foo;
+----------+------------+---------------------+
| deviceId | eventName  | loggedAt            |
+----------+------------+---------------------+
|        1 | foo        | 2020-09-18 21:27:21 |
|        1 | bar        | 2020-09-18 21:27:26 |
|        1 | last event | 2020-09-18 21:27:43 |  <--
|        2 | xyz        | 2020-09-18 21:27:37 |
|        2 | last event | 2020-09-18 21:27:55 |  <--
|        3 | last one   | 2020-09-18 21:28:04 |  <--
+----------+------------+---------------------+
```

and I want to select one row per `deviceId` with the most recent `loggedAt`. I've marked those rows with an arrow in the table above for clarity.

If I append  `group by id` in the above query, I get the notorious:

> Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'foo.eventName' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

and I don't want to change the `sql_mode`.

I've come pretty close to what I want using:

```
select deviceId, any_value(eventName), max(loggedAt) from foo group by deviceId;
```

but obviously the `any_value` returns a random result.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: @Akina: 8, but I think that this applies to 5.7 and later.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT deviceId, FIRST_VALUE(eventName) OVER (PARTITON BY deviceId ORDER BY loggedAt DESC), MAX(loggedAt) OVER (PARTITON BY deviceId) FROM foo;`. Applicable to 8+ only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is *a good thing*: it enforces fundamental SQL standard rules, about which MySQL has been lax for a long time. Even if you were disabling it, you would get the same result as what you are getting with `any_value()`.

You have a top-1-per group problem, where you cant the *entire row* that has the most recent date for each device. Aggregation is not the right tool for that, what you need is to filter the dataset.

One option uses a correlated subquery:

```
select f.*
from foo f
where f.loggedat = (
    select max(f1.loggedate) from foo where f1.deviceid = f.deviceid
)
```

In MySQL 8.0, you can also use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select f.*, row_number() over(partition by deviceid order by loggedat desc) rn
    from foo f
) f
where rn = 1
```